# Android application signed with same key store using same authenticator crashes due to SecurityException : caller UID is different from authenticator

Tags: android, keystore, securityexception

Its strange that app crashes in specific few devices and app signed with same key store with "shareUid tag"  shares data seamlessly but how could this crash occurs mostly in 5.1.1 and 4.4.2 os version of android.

Note: accountType is same and there is no typo error either  and even if its so , it should crash in all devices.

Reason for this crash: Signature miss match between the apps from amazon and google  play store. While the apps signed with same google key store and download from google play store works seamlessly and shares authentication.

Comment: Apps can crash if its trying to access accountmanger with same account type but signed with debug key(two diff apps - one with release key signed while the other with debug key signed) .. this issue making me go crazy .kindly help.

Comment: As it stands, there isn't enough information to definitively answer this question. Please post the SecurityException stack trace, and specify the exact tags, keystores, and signatures that you are using (just who is signing what, no need to post the actual certs and stores).

Comment: After few hours of analyzing the limited data available,  few app users had downloaded one of the app from Amazon app store ,which removes the signature signed with Google play store and signs it with its  own signature, As per the google docs for the modularity of  the apps, it needs to be signed with same key store. But the signature of the app from amazon app store and google play store are different and i had verified that there is difference in the signature of the app .

Comment: Eventually the first app which ever creates the account via account manager crashes the second app which tries uses  same authenticator due to SecurityException : caller UID is different from authenticator.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you figured this out. Bummer that Amazon does that.

Comment: @JerryWild Just to sum up, apps can access the AccountManager with same account type only if they are signed with the same certificate, correct? Isn't there a grant access screen visible when an app signed with a different key is requesting to access the account, as mentioned here - http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/?